# How to see updates to EBS volume when attached to multiple instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I have two ec2 instance running Ubuntu 18.04. I have created a Provisioned IOPS SSD (io1) volume and enabled multi-attach. I have successfully mounted the volume on both instances and can read and write to it without any issues. The problem now is if I modify a file on the shared volume from instance A, I cannot see the change on instance B without remounting the volume. Is there a way to make those updates immediately visible on both instances?

Comment: You can do that? TIL

Comment: *I have successfully mounted the volume on both instances and can read and write to it without any issues.* No, you didn't. If you used something like XFS or any other *non*-shared filesystem, you just haven't noted any issues.  ***YET***.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Figured as much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need a filesystem / app that's multi-attach aware. For example *Oracle RAC* can use such volumes, while normal filesystems like `ext4` or `xfs` can't. They are designed to be mounted on a single host only.

Let's step back - what are you trying to achieve? Share files between the instances I suppose? Your best bet is [**EFS** (Elastic File System)](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/) - an AWS cloud-native NFS service. Unless you've got a very specific need for multi-attach EBS and running some very special app that can make use of that I suggest you explore the EFS way instead. The need for multi-attach disks is rare, both in the cloud and outside.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: That's precisely what I need so EFS seems to fit the bill by its definition. I thought multi-attach works like an NFS. Thank you for disabusing me of that notion.

Comment: @codemonkey You probably want to check the filesystem you mounted from two instances at once. There are good chances it has been corrupted if you were using a filesystem which thought it had exclusive access to the volume (as most do).